# Simple ID Generator

Tags: java, beginner, random, serialization

**Task**

Write a program that can generate and manage collections of IDs. The user should determine how long the IDs have to be and what symbols they are composed of.

**Design choices made by me**

- The program functionalities are used via command line arguments
- A configuration file determines which scheme the IDs correspond to and where they are to be stored.
- It should be possible to manage several ID collections if the user wants it.
- Misuse should be intercepted, but the program does not have to be foolproof.

(You can find usage information by just calling `java Main`, or have a look at `Main.printHelp()`.)

**Example Usage**

```
C:\Programs> java Main help
Usage: java appname config:special/config/file <operation>
operations: new, show, del:<id>, custom:<custom_id>, help
If you do not provide a path to a config file, standard.config will be used.
You can only do one operation per program call.
C:\Programs> java Main new
RK9CE
C:\Programs> java Main new
KOZJO
C:\Programs> java Main new
8N23M
C:\Programs> java Main show
KOZJO, RTBXU, 8N23M
C:\Programs> java Main custom:bliblablub
Error: To long.
C:\Programs> java Main custom:blibl
Error: Your id contains forbidden symbols.
C:\Programs> java Main custom:BLIBL
Success.
C:\Programs> java Main del:BLIBL
Success.
```

**Question**

What do you think of my design choices? Did I manage to implement them elegantly? Are there design flaws in my source code?

**Source code and config-file**

*Main.java*

```
public class Main {
    private static String configFile = "standard.config";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int argIndex = 0;
        if (args.length > 0 && args.length <= 2) {
            boolean continueArgParsing = false;
            do {
                // check if user wants to provide a non-default config
                
                if (args[argIndex].startsWith("config:")) {
                    configFile = args[argIndex].split(":")[1];
                    if (args.length < 2) {
                        System.out.println("Please also tell me what you want to do.");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    continueArgParsing = true;
                    argIndex++;
                    continue;
                }
                
                IdManager man = IdManager.init(configFile);
                
                if (man == null) return;
                
                // check what user actually wants to do
                
                if (equalsOneOf(args[argIndex].toLowerCase(), "h", "-h", "/h", "help", "-help", "/help", "info")) {
                    printHelp();
                } else if (args[argIndex].equalsIgnoreCase("new")) {
                    System.out.println(man.createNewId());
                } else if (args[argIndex].startsWith("del:")) {
                    String idToDelete = args[argIndex].split(":")[1];
                    if (man.deleteId(idToDelete)) {
                        System.out.println("Success.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Error: There is no such id.");
                    }
                } else if (args[argIndex].equalsIgnoreCase("show")) { 
                    System.out.println(man.getIds());
                } else if (args[argIndex].startsWith("custom:")) {
                    String customId = args[argIndex].split(":")[1];
                    String errorMessage = man.addCustomId(customId);
                    if (errorMessage == null) {
                        System.out.println("Success.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    }
                }
                continueArgParsing = false;
            } while (continueArgParsing);
        } else {
            printHelp();
        }
    }
    
    private static void printHelp() {
        System.out.println("Usage: java appname config:special/config/file <operation>");
        System.out.println("operations: new, show, del:<id>, custom:<custom_id>, help");
        System.out.println("If you do not provide a path to a config file, standard.config will be used.");
        System.out.println("You can only do one operation per program call.");
    }
    
    // missing in java standard library
    private static boolean equalsOneOf(String string, String... values) {
        for (String value : values) {
            if (string.equals(value)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

*IdManager.java*

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class IdManager {
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    
    private String saveFile;
    private Set<String> ids;
    private String allowedSymbols;
    private int minLength;
    private int maxLength;
    
    private IdManager (String saveFile, String allowedSymbols, int minLength, int maxLength) {
        this.saveFile = saveFile;
        // remove all whitespace from allowedSymbols
        this.allowedSymbols = allowedSymbols.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        this.minLength = minLength;
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
        ids = new HashSet<String>();
        loadIdsFromFile();
    }
    
    public static IdManager init(String configFile) {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(configFile)) {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(fis);
            String saveFile = properties.getProperty("saveFile");
            String allowedSymbols = properties.getProperty("allowedSymbols");
            int minLength = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("minLength"));
            int maxLength = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("maxLength"));
            return new IdManager(saveFile, allowedSymbols, minLength, maxLength);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Could not read config file.");
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    private void loadIdsFromFile() {
        File file = new File(saveFile);
        if (!file.exists()) return;
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            ids = (HashSet<String>) ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private void saveIds() {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(saveFile))) {
            oos.writeObject(ids);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public String getIds() {
        return String.join(", " , ids);
    }
    
    public String createNewId() {
        // determine length
        int length = 0;
        if (maxLength == minLength) length = maxLength;
        else length = random.nextInt(maxLength - minLength + 1) + minLength;
        
        // repeat until new unique id is found
        String newId = "";
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                char symbolChar = allowedSymbols.charAt(random.nextInt(allowedSymbols.length()));
                String symbol = Character.toString(symbolChar);
                newId = newId + symbol;
            }
            if (ids.add(newId)) break;
            else newId = "";
        }
        saveIds();
        return newId;
    }
    
    // returns an error message if something went wrong
    // returns null when everything is fine
    public String addCustomId(String customId) {
        // check if length meets requirements
        if (customId.length() < minLength) return "Error: To short.";
        if (customId.length() > maxLength) return "Error: To long.";
        
        // check if only allowed symbols are in custom ids
        for (int i = 0; i < customId.length(); i++) {
            if (allowedSymbols.indexOf(customId.charAt(i)) == -1) return "Error: Your id contains forbidden symbols.";
        }
        
        // check if id is already in use
        if (!ids.add(customId)) return "Error: Id is already in use.";
        
        saveIds();
        return null;
    }
    
    // returns false if there is no such id
    public boolean deleteId(String id) {
        boolean returnValue = ids.remove(id);
        saveIds();
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

*standard.config*

```
allowedSymbols = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
minLength = 5
maxLength = 5
saveFile = ids.data
```

Comment: Is that the actual provided problem statement? You seem to have implemented rather a bit more than it's asking for.

Comment: Ive formulated the task for myself. I will add "generates and manages" to the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Single responsibility principle

Your `IdManager` class has multiple responsibilities.  It needs to know

1. How to generate an ID.
2. How to create an `IdManager` from a configuration file.
3. How to load IDs from a file.
4. How to save IDs to a file.
5. How to display a human readable `String` of the IDs.
6. What the properties of the `IdManager` are.

Now, we can lump these responsibilities together as all relating to IDs.  But there are better abstractions.  What if we break this into multiple classes?

1. `IdGenerator`
2. `IdManagerFromConfig`
3. `SetLoader<T>`
4. `SetStorer<T>`

And leave the last two in `IdManager`.

Now, only `IdGenerator` needs `Random`.  Only `IdManagerFromConfig` needs `Properties`.  Only `IdManagerFromConfig` and `SetLoader<T>` need `FileInputStream`.  Only `SetLoader<T>` needs `ObjectInputStream`.  Only `SetStorer<T>` needs `ObjectOutputStream` and `FileOutputStream`.  Only `SetLoader<T>` needs `HashSet`.
`IOException` and `Set` are the only imports needed by more than two classes.

#### Don't `catch` what you can't handle

> ```
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
> ```

What happens after this code?  Does your application simply not work?  Does it die somewhere with no data?

What would happen if this code did not exist?  I'm guessing that the exception would bubble to the top, your program would end, and it would display a stack trace.  Why are you replacing that with a manually displayed stack trace and a (presumably) non-functional program?

Until you are ready to do something with the exception, you should not catch it.  Instead, change the method to `throws` whatever exception.  Just printing a stack trace is useless behavior in a `catch` block.  You can get that by just ignoring the exception.

#### Simplify if you can

> ```
>         int length = 0;
>         if (maxLength == minLength) length = maxLength;
>         else length = random.nextInt(maxLength - minLength + 1) + minLength;
> ```

You can write this more simply as

```
        int length = minLength;
        if (maxLength != minLength) {
            length += random.nextInt(maxLength - minLength + 1);
        }
```

This will break if `maxLength` is less than `minLength`, as does your code.  It might be better to check for that case in the constructor or `init` rather than waiting until here to die.

This uses the block form of the `if`, as that is [highly recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2125066/6660678).  I don't want to dwell on this if you've already thought through the consequences.  But I would prefer code on which I'm working to always use the block form.  If you haven't taken the time to read the arguments against the statement form yet, you may find it useful to do so.

Since both branches of the `if` start with `minLength` while one adds to it, we can simply start with `minLength`.  Then we don't do the never used initialization to 0 and we only need one branch.  As a general rule, if code doesn't actually do anything, it makes sense to remove it.  Otherwise, people can find themselves wasting time trying to figure out what the code does.

#### Minimize scope

> ```
>         String newId = "";
>         while (true) {
>             for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
>                 char symbolChar = allowedSymbols.charAt(random.nextInt(allowedSymbols.length()));
>                 String symbol = Character.toString(symbolChar);
>                 newId = newId + symbol;
>             }
>             if (ids.add(newId)) break;
>             else newId = "";
>         }
>         saveIds();
>         return newId;
> ```

You can reduce the scope of `newId`, since you don't need it after the `return` and do need to reset it between invocations.  Consider

```
        PrimitiveIterator.OfInt indexes = random.ints(0, allowedSymbols.length).iterator();
        while (true) {
            StringBuilder newId = new StringBuilder(length);
            while (newId.length() < length) {
                newId.append(allowedSymbols[indexes.nextInt()]);
            }

            if (ids.add(newId.toString())) {
                saveIds();
                return newId.toString();
            }
        }
```

Now it resets automatically.

This generates a random `IntStream` rather than repeatedly calling `nextInt`.  Mostly this saves having to specify `allowedSymbols.length` each time.  It may also allow some optimizations.

Note that `Random` is not cryptographically secure.  You should use a different implementation if randomness really matters.  E.g. [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html).  But if true randomness is not important, `Random` is faster.  You might allow callers to pass a `Random` into the constructor so that they can specify whether security or speed is more important for their application.

This changes `allowedSymbols` to a character array for simpler access.  Note that you can still pass a `String` into the constructor.  Then just do

```
        this.allowedSymbols = allowedSymbols.replaceAll("\\s", "").toCharArray();
```

When building a string, `StringBuilder` is what you want to use.  The compiler would probably have done this for you, but now you don't have to worry about it.  Alternately, you could have done this with a character array as well.  Since you already know the length at this point.

Moving the `return` into the loop is the last piece needed to reduce the scope of `newId`.